# How to deselect a row when another row tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is what I want to archive: deselect the "English" row when the second Chinese row tapped, or conversely.

[image: Picture]

I want only one checkmark to be shown, not all of them. Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!.accessoryType == .checkmark  {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!.accessoryType = .none
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.isEnabled = false
    } else if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!.accessoryType == .none   {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!.accessoryType = .checkmark
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: You can think of having a variable which will hold selected row index. And check that selectedRowIndex variable on cellForRowAtIndexPath...with indexPath.row.... On didselectRow you can set the value of selectedRowIndex and reload tableview it will work.

Comment: If you want only one item be selected, you can set tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false

Comment: Whats the problem with the code without the redundant (unnecessary) words and properly formatted?

Comment: @LeoDabus It doesn’t work, if the UITableViewCellAccessoryTye are removed. You will not select any one of the row.

Comment: Just force unwrap the cellForRow method considering that it is a valid indexPath

Comment: @chengsam Thanks, Sir. But I’m afraid it doesn’t work.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, force unwrap the cellForRow method works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got an answer. Here you go:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!.accessoryType = .checkmark
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!.accessoryType = .none
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    }
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Cool. Thanks a lot, Leo.